# How to close a specific java window with a bat?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat that starts 3 separate java windows like so:

```
start java -jar somejar.jar
start java -jar _the_jar_I_want_to_close_.jar
start java -jar someotherjar.jar
```

I need a bat command that closes ***ONLY*** _the_jar_I_want_to_close_.jar. Unfortunately the only thing that differentiates these windows is the PID, but the PID changes every time they're launched.

### Here's what I've tried

1. Taskkill by PID `taskkill /PID  ####` **Problem:** The PID is not constant.
2. Killing all processes from java `taskkill /IM java.exe` **Problem:** There are 2 other java windows that I don't want to stop
3. Killing all processes by image name: `taskkill /IM java` **Problem:** Same as above, only need to kill one window, not all three.

### Possibilities?

1. Is it possible to name the windows when I start them, so I can reference that name later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `start "title 4 kills"`

```
start "java 1" java -jar somejar.jar
start "java 2" java -jar _the_jar_I_want_to_close_.jar
start "java 3" java -jar someotherjar.jar

taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq "java 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes two steps:

1. Find the PID (taken from this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/126502/how-to-get-own-process-pid-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=2 USEBACKQ" %f IN (`tasklist /NH /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq _the_jar_I_want_to_close_*"`) Do set ourPID=%f
   ```
2. Kill the process by PID:

   ```
   taskkill /F /PID %ourPID%
   ```